# unable to write the ouput of an object to file in R

Tags: r

I have an R script that does bunch of stuff and at the end of the script run, I like to write the final output to file. The final object call p contains the data like this:

dput(p)

```
"[{\"name\":\"loess\",\"data\":[[1373241600000,3.49571041760408],[1373241660000,3.4844505982485],[1373241720000,3.47324293684199],[1373241780000,3.46208745646435],[1373241840000,3.45098418019539],[1373241900000,3.43993313111491],[1373241960000,3.42893433230273],[1373242020000,3.41798780683864],[1373242080000,3.40709357780246],[1373242140000,3.39625166827399],[1373242200000,3.38546210133304],[1373242260000,3.37472490005941],[1373242320000,3.36404008753291],[1373242380000,3.35340768683334],[1373242440000,3.34282772104051],[1373242500000,3.33230021323422],[1373242560000,3.32182518649429],[1373242620000,3.31140266390052],[1373242680000,3.30103266853271],[1373242740000,3.29071522347067],[1373242800000,3.28045035179421],[1373242860000,3.27023807658312],[1373242920000,3.26007842091723],[1373242980000,3.24997140787633],[1373243040000,3.23991706054023],[1373243100000,3.22991540198874],[1373243160000,3.21996645530166],[1373243220000,3.2100702435588],[1373243280000,3.20022678983996],[1373243340000,3.19043611722495],[1373243400000,3.18069824879358],[1373243460000,3.17101320762565],[1373243520000,3.16138101680096],[1373243580000,3.15180169939934],[1373243640000,3.14227527850057],[1373243700000,3.13280177718446],[1373243760000,3.12338121853083],[1373243820000,3.11401362561948],[1373243880000,3.10469902153021],[1373243940000,3.09543742934283],[1373244000000,3.08622887213715],[1373244060000,3.07707337299297],[1373244120000,3.0679709549901],[1373244180000,3.05892164120834],[1373244240000,3.0499254547275],[1373244300000,3.04098241862739],[1373244360000,3.03209255598781],[1373244420000,3.02325588988857],[1373244480000,3.01447244340947],[1373244540000,3.00574223963032],[1373244600000,2.99706530163093],[1373244660000,2.9884416524911],[1373244720000,2.97987131529064],[1373244780000,2.97135431310935],[1373244840000,2.96289066902704],[1373244900000,2.95448040612352],[1373244960000,2.94612354747859],[1373245020000,2.93782011617205],[1373245080000,2.92957013528372],[1373245140000,2.92137362789341],[1373245200000,2.9132306170809],[1373245260000,2.90514112592602],[1373245320000,2.89710517750857],[1373245380000,2.88912279490835],[1373245440000,2.88119400120517],[1373245500000,2.87331881947884],[1373245560000,2.86549727280916],[1373245620000,2.85772938427594],[1373245680000,2.85001517695898],[1373245740000,2.84235467393809],[1373245800000,2.83474789829308],[1373245860000,2.82719487310374],[1373245920000,2.8196956214499],[1373245980000,2.81225016641135],[1373246040000,2.8048585310679],[1373246100000,2.79752073849936],[1373246160000,2.79023681178553],[1373246220000,2.78300677400622],[1373246280000,2.77583064824123],[1373246340000,2.76870845757037],[1373246400000,2.76164022507344],[1373246460000,2.75462597383026],[1373246520000,2.74766572692063],[1373246580000,2.74075950742435],[1373246640000,2.73390733842123],[1373246700000,2.72710924299107],[1373246760000,2.72036524421369],[1373246820000,2.71367536516889],[1373246880000,2.70703962893647],[1373246940000,2.70045805859624],[1373247000000,2.693930677228],[1373247060000,2.68745750791157],[1373247120000,2.68103857372674],[1373247180000,2.67467389775333],[1373247240000,2.66836350307114],[1373247300000,2.66210741275998],[1373247360000,2.65590564989964],[1373247420000,2.64975823756995],[1373247480000,2.6436651988507],[1373247540000,2.63762655682169],[1373247600000,2.63164233456275],[1373247660000,2.62571255515366],[1373247720000,2.61983724167425],[1373247780000,2.61401641720431],[1373247840000,2.60825010482364],[1373247900000,2.60253832761207],[1373247960000,2.59688110864938],[1373248020000,2.5912784710154],[1373248080000,2.58573043778991],[1373248140000,2.58023703205274],[1373248200000,2.57479827688368],[1373248260000,2.56941419536255],[1373248320000,2.56408481056914],[1373248380000,2.55881014558327],[1373248440000,2.55359022348473],[1373248500000,2.54842506735335],[1373248560000,2.54331470026891],[1373248620000,2.53825914531123],[1373248680000,2.53325842556012],[1373248740000,2.52831256409537],[1373248800000,2.5234215839968],[1373248860000,2.51858550834422],[1373248920000,2.51380436021742],[1373248980000,2.50907816269621],[1373249040000,2.50440693886041],[1373249100000,2.49979317477766],[1373249160000,2.49523927109528],[1373249220000,2.49074512276254],[1373249280000,2.48631062472871],[1373249340000,2.48193567194306],[1373249400000,2.47762015935487]]}]"
```

I tried:

```
sink("output.txt")
cat(p)
sink()
```

did not work

I tried(

```
writeLines(p, "output.txt")
```

did not work

I tried

```
accepted  fileConn<-file("output.txt")
writeLines(p, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

it did not work.

When I execute any of these commands right from the R console it works. But I need this to work with the R script since I will run this script on an scheduled basis. Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: It is not clear att all. What do you have as input/outpus?  seems like you try to parse some json text?

Comment: @agstudy, I need to write the ouput of p to a file.

Comment: So you have an r object called p ? If so, can you put a `dput(p)` and add it to your question please.

Comment: it works from the R console but when I execute the same line of codes withing the R script, the output file is not created.

Comment: @agstudy, I posted the output of p in my initial post, it is a json object.

Comment: No. it is result of `cat`. I need the `dput(p)`, easier to manipulate., and give me the structure of your object.  (Note I didn't downvote)

Comment: when I am on the R console, I can write to the file. But when I try to execute the same code via the R script, it does not work. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Where's your working directory? And do you have write permission for it?

Comment: add `getwd()` to your script to make sure you're looking in the right place for your file(s)

Comment: You wrote "it did not work" three times but never described what you did to examine the file. Most of us are thinking you don't know where to look for it. `sink(out.txt');cat(obj);sink()`  "works" for us at least in the sense to seeing the same think in the txt file as we see at the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the commands work from console but not from the script its most likely a function of write permissions and/or wrong path (as mentioned by others). Within my scripts I always provide full path. I build a hierarchy to keep track of things:

```
basedir = "C:/Users/Rdas01/Documents/FTPHome"
inputdir = file.path(basedir,"Input")
outdir = file.path(basedir,"Output")
reportdir = file.path(basedir,"Report")

f_Rdata = file.path(outdir,"Data.Rdata")
f_out = file.path(outdir,"output.txt")

# Do your calculations here

write.csv(p,file = f_out, row.names=F)
save.image(file = f_Rdata)
print(f_out)
print(f_Rdata)
```